Как создать виртуальную среду с определенным интепретатором Python?
Я выполнил команду:
py -3.8.10 -m venv env

Получил ошибку:

No suitable Python runtime found
Pass --list (-0) to see all detected environments on your machine
or set environment variable PYLAUNCHER_ALLOW_INSTALL to use winget
or open the Microsoft Store to the requested version.

Выполнил другую команду:
virtualenv -p PATH\интепретатор3.8.10 env

В этом случае не может найти файл. Писал полностью все название файла интерпретатора, но безуспешно. Я не понимаю как создать виртуальную среду.
Устанавливал версию Python 3.8.10 как второстепенною без галочки на PATH. Работаю в операционной системе Windows 11.

"не может найти файл" - уточните, что и какой файл не может найти. Речь о командной оболочке, которая не может найти virtualenv, или об этой команде, которая не может найти пайтон по заданному пути? Если второе, то пытались ли вы запустить установленную версию пайтон напрямую и с каким итогом?

Приведите в вопросе полные тексты ошибок, полные команды, которые вы запускали и т.д. Пересказа недостаточно.

Можно попробовать uv использовать, создание виртуального окружения с нужной версией python - uv venv --python 3.8.10 (он сам должен скачать нужную версию Python, если она не установлена). Под linux точно работает, под windows не пробовал, но теоретически должно.

Vitalizzare оно не находило интепретатор пайтона 3.8.10 по пути. Запускать? Ну, попытался, безуспешно. Зашел в директорию где лижет интепретатор нужной версии и выдало:  огромную ошибку с какими-то подробностями выше, а в конце было  Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding Python runtime state: core initialized ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'.     Все ошибку вписать не смог, не вместилось.

insolor создать то создало, а вот активировать виртуальную среду не могу. Выдает ту же ошибку, что и при попытке запуска интепретатора напрямую.

Какую именно такую же? "No suitable Python runtime found"?

insolor имменноо

Загвоздка состояла в том, что я использовал некорректные символы в названии папок...
Теперь uv venv --python 3.8.10 прекрасно работает, могу предположить, что и команды которые я пытался использовать ранее также работают. ГМ...
Все работает как надо, спасибо за помощь.
